# Fast way to load a lot of indexes (from a Pandas dataframe) into a sparse matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, sparse-matrix

I've got a large Pandas dataframe with 1.500.000 rows, and one column contains lists with numbers. You can imagine it like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lists' : [[0, 1, 2], [6, 7, 8], [3, 4, 5]]})
```

but way bigger. in the end I want a matrix, that looks like this

```
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

so the row index of the df is the row index of the matrix and the numbers in the list are the column indexes that need to be set to True.

The matrix will be of shape 1.500.000 x 30.000, but this takes too much RAM, so I save the matrix with lil_matrix(), and then later I can form the matrix batch for batch.

The way I do this right now is the following:

```
sparse_matrix = sparse.lil_matrix((1.500.000, 30.000), dtype=bool)
list_with_lists = df["lists"].tolist()
for i, list in enumerate(list_with_lists):
    for number in list:
        sparse_matrix[i, number] = True
```

It works, but it takes a couple of minutes and I really hope there is a faster way as this takes too much times. Does anyone know a faster way?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this will work with the `scipy.sparse.lil_matrix`, but try using advanced indexing:

```
rows = np.arange(m.shape[0])[:, np.newaxis]
cols = df['lists'].tolist()
m[rows, cols] = 1
```

Basically, we're saying set every `[row, column]` pair found here to `True`. `row` looks like `[[1], [2], [3], ..., N]` for a `N * M` matrix and `cols` is your series.

With a test case

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'lists' : [[0, 1, 2], [6, 7, 8], [3, 4, 5]]})

m = np.zeros((3, 9), dtype=bool)

rows = np.arange(m.shape[0])[:, np.newaxis]
cols = df['lists'].tolist()
m[rows, cols] = True

print(m.view(np.int8))
```

I get

```
[[1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`dok_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.html) with its `update` function. You will need to prepare a list of the form ((row_idx, col_idx), val) and pass it in the `update` function. Here, I tried to use the `map` and `reduce` to create the list.

```
from itertools import chain
from scipy import sparse

df = pd.DataFrame({'lists' : [[0, 1, 2], [6, 7, 8], [3, 4, 5]]})
sparse_matrix = sparse.dok_matrix((1500000, 30000), dtype=bool)
list_with_lists = df["lists"].tolist()


update_list = chain.from_iterable(map(lambda l, r: [((r, i), 1) for i in l], 
                                      list_with_lists, 
                                      range(len(list_with_lists))))    

# update_list 
[((0, 0), 1),
 ((0, 1), 1),
 ((0, 2), 1),
 ((1, 6), 1),
 ((1, 7), 1),
 ((1, 8), 1),
 ((2, 3), 1),
 ((2, 4), 1),
 ((2, 5), 1)]

sparse_matrix.update(update_list)
```

#### Timing

Setup

```
from numpy.random import randint
df = pd.DataFrame({'lists' : [randint(0, 30000, 10) for i in range(10000)]})
list_with_lists = df["lists"].tolist()
```

Using `lil_matrix` with double-loop update

```
sparse_matrix = sparse.lil_matrix((1500000, 30000), dtype=bool)
%%timeit  # OP's original way of adding using lil_matrix
for i, list in enumerate(list_with_lists):
    for number in list:
        sparse_matrix[i, number] = True
635 ms ± 26.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Using `dok_matrix` with `update`.

```
sparse_matrix = sparse.dok_matrix((1500000, 30000), dtype=bool)
%%timeit # updating using `update` function in dok_matrix
update_list = chain.from_iterable(map(lambda l, r: [((r, i), 1) for i in l], 
                              list_with_lists, 
                              range(len(list_with_lists))))    
sparse_matrix.update(update_list)
48.7 ms ± 6.84 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

`dok_matrix`, however, may be slow in other matrix operations.